# Backup software with caching until target available

Tags: windows, backup

So I am looking into migrating from Acronis that's been going downhill, and looking at Veeam Agent specs noticed they have a nice feature called Backup Cache, wherein a local backup cache is created if the backup target location is unavailable, so that it can be quickly copied when the external location becomes available. Their realisation is a bit limited though (no caches for file level backups).
Anyone knows of software that offers similar functionality?